# Polynomial curve not fitting with results

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am getting large CD value for my drag polar curve fit.

The following is my lift and drag coefficient values:

Lift Coefficient

```
[-0.2863876  -0.15198764 -0.00709039  0.1414652   0.28727075  0.43092027
  0.57339435  0.71901446  0.95383017  1.00155515  1.04740696  0.93310272]
```

Drag Coefficient

```
[-0.02768897 -0.03168675 -0.03116817 -0.02166403 -0.00677296  0.01566423
  0.04477065  0.08153319  0.16150749  0.19508941  0.21802003  0.12811101]
```

The following is my code:

```
def test_func(CL, k, CD_0):
    return k*(CL**2) + CD_0  # drag polar function

popt, pcov = curve_fit(test_func, CD, CL, p0=[1, 0.01])

k_opt, CD_0_opt = popt 

CL_model = np.linspace(min(CL), max(CL), 100)
CD_model = test_func(CL_model, k_opt, CD_0_opt)
```

[image: plot]

I tried adjusting the initial guesses p0, there was no effect on the curve fit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I'm out of my wheelhouse, but FWIW, I don't know what you're asking. Check out [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title and showing what research you've done.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, but I think you've just flipped what "x" and "y" are in your head. If you look at the plot you provided, how can you expect curve fit to fit a function to this? It fails the function test as there are multiple possible values for $C_L$ corresponding to a single value of $C_D$.

Looking at your function, it seems to predict values for $C_D$ from values of $C_L$, so in this case your "x" is the coefficient of lift and your y is the coefficient of drag. If you flip this around and use `curve_fit` it works fine for me -- see code and plot below using your coefficient data:

```py
#copying data from your post, but note that your last two data points are a little weird (either outliers with high error or maybe you copied them wrong or out of order?)
CL = np.array([-0.2863876, -0.15198764, -0.00709039, 0.1414652, 0.28727075, 0.43092027, 0.57339435, 0.71901446, 0.95383017, 1.00155515, 1.04740696, 0.93310272])
CD = np.array([-0.02768897, -0.03168675, -0.03116817, -0.02166403, -0.00677296, 0.01566423, 0.04477065, 0.08153319, 0.16150749, 0.19508941, 0.21802003, 0.12811101])

def test_func(CL, k, CD_0):
    return k*(CL**2) + CD_0  # your test function, which predicts CD (y) from values of CL (x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(test_func,CL,CD,p0=[1.,0.01]) #note that CL is first because it is the "x" variable and CD is second because that's what we are trying to match for "y"

#plot results
plt.scatter(CL,CD,marker="x",label="Data",c="dodgerblue")
CL_model = np.linspace(np.min(CL), np.max(CL), 100)
CD_model = test_func(CL_model, k_opt, CD_0_opt)
plt.plot(CL_model,CD_model,label=r"model: k = {:.2f}, $CD_0$ = {:.2f}".format(popt[0],popt[1]),c="orange")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel(r"$C_L$")
plt.ylabel(r"$C_D$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

But also, as @JJacquelin points out in their answer below, you may want to consider changing the function you use to fit the data as picking a function of the form y = x^2 + c imposes that the minimum must be at exactly x = 0, whereas your data seem to show that this isn't the case. And you should also check your data and discard any data points for which you know there isn't a physical justification for using this kind of model.

Comment: The last data point is beyond the stall point, so the lift coefficient CL will drop. But the negative drag coefficients are an interesting take on perpetual-motion machines.

Answer (score 2):

With :  x = Lift Coefficient and y = Drag Coefficient$ we observe that the minimum of y(x) is not exactly at x=0.

Thus the equation model  y(x) = a * x^2 + b * x + c  is better than  y(x) = A * x^2 + C

[image]

Note : The last point (x=0.93310272 , y=0.12811101) was not considered in the quadratic regression. It is irrelevant because too close to the break point.

Comment: I think you've labelled your curves wrong, given that your blue curve matches my orange curve in previous answer...

Comment: @kirklong. You are right. I will correct the labels. Thank you.